# Attribute Selector

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to use this CSS for my WordPress website to have each post tags unique background color.

```
    a[href="http://www.example.com/tag/science/"] {
    background: red!important;
    color: white;
}
```

If I check this CSS on browsers inspect element it works fine. But when I adding it my custom CSS file. It's not working on the live page. Is there anything I am missing out? I did clear the cache.

Thank You,
Mazhar

Comment: No, It's good and works for me. Do a inspect element

Comment: Yes, it works fine in inspect element but when I putting it on custom.css file and checking on the live page it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the same above CSS in dashboard -> Appearance -> Customizer! it worked then.

Thanks